# How to catch null value on http response

Tags: groovy

I have the following code method which is used to test for an existing user in MSGraph API

```
public String getGuestUserId(String AuthToken,String userEmail){

    String _userId
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_user_url + "?")

        http.request(GET) {

            requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            //uri.query = [ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"].toString()
            uri.query=[$filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"]
           
            headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken    

            response.success = { resp, json ->
                //as the retunr json alue is an array collection we need to get the first element as we request all time one record from the filter
                **_userId=json.value[0].id**
                                    
            }

            // user ID not found : error 404
            response.'404' = { resp ->       
                _userId = 'Not Found'
            }

        }
        _userId
    }
```

This method works fine when the user is existing and will return properly from the success response the user ID property.

The issue I get is that if the user is not existing, the ID field is not existing either and the array is empty.

How can I handle efficiently that case and return a meaning full value to the caller like "User Does not exist"

I have try a catch exception in the response side but seems doe snot to work

Any idea how can I handle the test like if the array[0] is empty or does not contains any Id property, then return something back ?

Thanks for help
regards

Comment: maybe just throw an exception if your outer code expects exception... `response.'404' = { resp -> throw new Exception("User not found") }`

Comment: thanks for your reply @daggett, but the problem is that when no user is found, the http response is Success but the Id property of the _userId=json.value[0] does not exist as the value[] is empty, how can I check this ?

Comment: `if( json.value.size()>0 )` ?

Comment: `if( json.value ){}` should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be widely accepted practice not to catch NPE. Instead, one should check if something is null.

In your case:

1. You should check if `json.value` is not empty
2. You also should check if `id` is not null.

Please also note that handling exceptions in lambdas is always tricky.

You can change the code to:

```
http.request(GET) {
  requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
  uri.query=[$filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"]
       
  headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken

  if (json.value && json.value[0].id) {
    response.success = { resp, json -> **_userId=json.value[0].id** }
  } else {
    // Here you can return generic error response, like the one below
    // or consider more granular error reporting
    response.'404' = { resp -> _userId = 'Not Found'}
  }
}
```